# Change styles of a window based on view(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have multiple windows and a common style. I need to the change the border background color based on windows. For ex if window 'A' is shown then background should be black if 'B' then white so on. I am using a customized basewindowview. Can i use datatrigger?

Code Style.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle"
   TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
<Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
<Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource WindowPadding}"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
            <Grid Visibility="{TemplateBinding Visibility}">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                        Grid.RowSpan="3">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="PART_TitleBar"
                            Style="{StaticResource WindowTitleBarBorderStyle}"
                            Padding="0">                                    
                        </Border>
                    <Border Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource WindowBorderStyle}">
                        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>              
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName="MessageBox",RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="PART_TitleBar" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </DataTrigger>                        
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

and this is my view

```
<views:BaseWindowView  
    x:Class="mv.Office.Presentation.Views.MessageBoxWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:mv.Office.Presentation.Common.Views;assembly=mv.Office.Presentation.Common"
    xmlns:viewModles="clr-namespace:mv.Office.Presentation.ViewModels"
    xmlns:w="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=PresentationFramework"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:mv.Office.Presentation.Common.Converters;assembly=mv.Office.Presentation.Common"
    x:TypeArguments="viewModles:MessageBoxViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Style="{DynamicResource MessageWindowStyle}"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" MaxWidth="400" MinWidth="200"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Name=MessageBox
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:ObjectToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ObjectToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <converters:MessageBoxImageToBitmapImageConverter x:Key="MessageBoxImageToBitmapImageConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
</views:BaseWindowView>
```

Here i am using datatrigger to change the values and elementname is Name of the view.

Comment: Let each window set its own `BorderBrush`, and refer to that in your control template with a template binding: `{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}`.

Comment: Hey Pieter so you want me to set in datatrigger or in each view. could you please modify the code. i could understand much better

Comment: No, you don't need data triggers for this (not in your control template anyway). Each individual window sets its own `BorderBrush` property. Window 'A' sets it to `Black`, window 'B' sets it to `White`. Then, in your control template, you'll set your title bar border's background as following: `Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"`.